# Decompress GZ file from windows command line

Tags: cmd, gzip

I know there's a windows built in command to decompress tar.gz files such as

```
tar -zcvf samples_compressed.tar.gz /path/to/sample/directory/
```

but, if you use with a GZ file it doesn't work, I've been looking for a way to decompress the GZ file with CMD but still not finding a solution.

Any ideas to workaround this?

Thanks!

Comment: `tar -zcvf samples_compressed.tar.gz` is `tar -z -c -v -f samples_compressed.tar.gz` or `tar --gzip --create --verbose --file=samples_compressed.tar.gz`. Do you see your mistake? You posted a command line to __create__ a __tar__ archive in __verbose__ mode and __gzip *COMPRESS*__ the tar archive file into file `samples_compressed.tar.gz`. So this command line will not work on any operating system to decompress a gzip compressed tar archive. `tar -xf samples_compressed.tar.gz` decompresses such an archive in current directory into the current directory. `tar --help` outputs help.

Comment: Line above is an example, the main thing here is.
If I decompress sample.tar.gz works
If I decompres sample.gz does not work

Comment: `tar` uses the program `gzip` to compress a tar archive after creating it and to decompress a gzip archive to get the tar archive extracted next by tar. So if you can decompress a `sample.tar.gz` archive file (tar archive compressed to a gzip archive) successfully with `tar -xf sample.tar.gz`, `gzip` is also installed and found by `tar`. So run `gzip --help` for the command line options supported by `gzip` to decompress archive file `sample.gz` with using just `gzip`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you perform the task like this:

```batch-file
"%__AppDir__%tar.exe" -xf ".\samples_compressed.tar.gz" -C "P:\ath\to\sample\directory"
```

or, I suppose, like this:

```batch-file
"%__AppDir__%tar.exe" -xf ".\samples_compressed.tar.gz" -C ".\relativepath\to\sampledirectory"
```

Answer (score 0):

7zip offers `7z.exe` as a command-line option for extraction. I know of no built-in method for similar results, If you say `tar` isn't working for you.

```
7z e -y <target>
```